# Smoothing out values in Tone.js

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

[In this ramping example](https://tonejs.github.io/examples/rampTo.html) of Tone.js, ramping acts not as a "smoother", but almost like a delay. It seems like when it receives a value, then instead of starting to ramp towards that, it would schedule another ramp after the current one.

You can see this behavior when you drag the harmony slider fast enough. You'll notice that it insists on going through all the values that it previously had.

How would I get a behavior in which only the last value is considered?

Answer (score 0):

This just has to do with the implementation of the slider. A function is called on the "drag" event so that every couple of pixels the slider is moved, the function is called. Meaning you are right there are multiple rampTo functions being called one after another.

If you wanted to get only the last value to be called, you would have to create a dragEnd property on the slider so that once the slider has reached its final value, the function will be called. Or check out the Lodash documents on throttle which would call the function a maximum of once every 'x' amount of time (https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#throttle).

Hope that helps.